# What files in Eclipse contains code templates and keyboard bindings?

Tags: eclipse, templates, configuration, backup, configuration-files

I have three common workplaces where I use the `Eclipse` IDE.

A nice trick when using multiple common workplaces is to copy certain configuration files to Dropbox, and link to them in the original configuration location. This way, all settings and changes are instantly available in your other workplaces.

You've got your `workspace` with a whopping 100 megabytes of files. You've got your `.eclipse` which is closing in on 200 megabytes.

I would like to know which specific files contain my custom javascript code templates, and which contains my keyboard shortcuts, so I can share these, and only these, with myself through Dropbox.

Ideally, I'd like a list of of certain settings and their locations so I can choose to share more. But I haven't found something like this on Google.

Why am I not just sharing my entire workspace and configuration directory? Well, first, it is crazy big. Second, Eclipse is modular. In some places I use certain modules that I don't use elsewhere. And you all know that modules/plugins are a crazy mess of files and configuration from which there is no escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can copy your `~/workspace/eclipse/.metadata` to somewhere. Change a preference, and sync your workspace to your backup in order to find out what files are changed.

You'll find that a lot of settings are in `~/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/`. The javascript templates and other javascript options are in `~/workspace/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs`

- org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs = Code Templates
- org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs = Syntax Coloring
- org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs = Text Editors

Answer (score 0):

You can try to export Eclipse preferences from one workspace and export them to other workspace. If it doesn't work for your, enter a bug against corresponding Eclipse project.